# How would you out a shape like this on sub div mesh?

Tags: modeling

I tried boolean and that created more problems than I had before. Tried knife, but that kinda ends up in ngon...

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you talking about the inner surface? I'm not sure in what way you're struggling with it, could you please elaborate?